# Is $\sup|f(x)|_{\{x \in \Bbb R: |f(x)|\leq a\}}=a?$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function. Let $a \geq 0$ and
$$A=\{x \in \Bbb R : |f(x)|\leq a\}$$

Question: Is $\sup_A |f(x)| = a$?

I was just able to prove that $\sup_A |f(x)|\leq a?$, since $|f(x)|\leq a$ for all $x \in A$, but I can't get the reverse inequality.

Comment: No, Take $f\equiv 0$ and $a>0$ then $A=\mathbb{R}$ but $\sup \limits_A |f|=0<a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: take $f$ defined as $\forall x: f(x)=0$ and $a=1$.